# Does the global dimension gldim R equal the projective dimension of R as bimodule over its enveloping algebra?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology

I know that generally the answer is no, for example the weyl algebra。
But is this true for commutative algebra？ or we may restrict to affine commutative algebras。

Maybe ，it is a classical result. So, please let me know the reference. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $A$ is non-negatvely graded and connected, with $A_0=k$ your base field. Then the same is true of the enveloping algebra $A^e$.

As with all algebras, we have $\def\gldim{\operatorname{gldim}}\def\pdim{\operatorname{pdim}}\gldim A\leq\pdim_{A^e}A$.

Suppose $\pdim_{A^e}A=n<\infty$. By taking a *minimal* resolution of $A$ as an $A$-bimodule of length $n$ to compute, we see that $\def\Ext{\operatorname{Ext}}\Ext^n_{A^e}(A,k)\neq0$. Now $k\cong\hom_k(k,k)$ as a bimodule, and $\Ext^\bullet_{A^e}(A,\hom_k(k,k))\cong\Ext^\bullet_A(k,k)$: this tells us that $\gldim A\geq n$, so your equality holds in this case. If the dimension is infinite, the same works.

Something similar can be done if $A$ is local noetherian with the base field as residue field.

**On the other hand**, the equality does not hold always, even in the affine commutative case. For example, suppose $L/k$ is a finite field extension of your ground field $k$ which is not separable. Since separability of $L/k$ is the same thing as $L$ being a separable $k$-algebra, we have that $L$ is not a projective $L$-bimodule and therefore $$\pdim_{L^e}L\geq1>0=\gldim L.$$

Comment: Of course, this counterexample will not work if $k$ is perfect. Then just take $L=k(t)$ with $t$ trascendental over $k$; then $L$ is not a separable $k$-algebra (because separable algebras over fields are finite dimensional) and the same reasoning applies.

Comment: A sillier counterexample is: pick any algebra $A$ whose left and right global dimensions are different (such this exist); since the projective dimension of $A$ as an $A$-bimodule is side-agnostic, it must be different to at least one of the two global dimensions!

Comment: Well，thank you for the explainations. So, if the gldim is finite，then how about the bimodule dimension of an affine commutative k-algebra？ Is that still finite since your examples implies that these two numbers may not be the same. 

PS: Is the bimodule dimension of L in your example finite? 

Thanks again. 

Happy new year to you！^_^

Comment: I know that for commutative affine algbera over a field of characteristic zero, then global dimension is finite iff the bimodule projective dimension is finite which is also equivalent to say that the algebra is regular.

Comment: Can you explain why $Ext_{A^e}^n (A,k) \neq 0$ and why $Ext_{A^e}(A,hom_k(k,k))=Ext_A(k,k)$?